# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg' with Adobe Photoshop API in Python on MacOS

Tags: python, photoshop

I am looking to build a program that edits text within an Adobe Photoshop file (.psd), and have found multiple libraries that will help me do this, but all seem to be limited to Windows machines. Are there any alternatives on MacOS that I haven't found yet?

Whenever I try use the Windows modules, I always get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'.

Any ideas on ways around this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're unable to get anything else to work, GIMP's python-fu might be an option.

Comment: winreg, as the name implies, is for Windows

Comment: Adobe seems to have a cloud API https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/ might be your best bet